# A boolean algebra question ( K-Map & MPS)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to solve this question into a K-Map or a truth table. But I would prefer a K-Map. As we know for Product of sums, the terms inside each bracket must be sums of function which in this case is,

[image]

I am stuck with rather a simple doubt than solving the actual question that 2 bracket has product inside. I don't know how to draw that into a K-Map shall I go like,

```
c' + (a + b + d) 
c' + (a' + b' + d')
```

separately ?

Or should I evaluate them by AND operation, which I don't think is the way.

[image]

For reference, I have added the K-Map here, **but don't know what Maps to what?**
Can you please help me in identifying which expression maps to what in the K-Map? Thank you

Comment: Your k-map looks good to me. I think you nailed it. But I don't think I understand what you want from there. You've got a good k-map. What is it that you want from there, again?

Comment: [This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3j6p.png) from your k-map. I think you did a good job preparing it.

Comment: This expression is difficult to evaluate, how did you came to simplified expression before making a K-map @jonk